# eclipse import org.apache.http warning (android java)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**i'm newbie**

i wanna call data from db but import warning

import org.apache.http.<strike>HttpEntity</strike>;

import org.apache.http.<strike>HttpResponse</strike>;

import org.apache.http.<strike>NameValuePair</strike>;

import org.apache.http.client.<strike>HttpClient</strike>;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.<strike>UrlEncodedFormEntity</strike>;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.<strike>HttpPost</strike>;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.<strike>DefaultHttpClient</strike>;

import org.apache.http.message.<strike>BasicNameValuePair</strike>;

my libs have httpcore-4.0.1.jar

im already httpcore-4.0.1.jar in config crosspath

thankyou

Comment: Please tell me you dont have `<strike></strike>` in your code.

Comment: sorry im not profess in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the new Android 6.0 Marshmallow SDK, where these classes have been removed. More information under this link:
[Click here to see the SDK changes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html)